# The request message was malformed :: Error creating new authz :: DNS name does not have enough labels

Tags: apache, ssl, https, dns

I'm trying to setup SSL/HTTPS with certbot, but I'm getting this error:

```
The request message was malformed :: Error creating new authz :: DNS name does not have enough labels
```

I'm using Apache2 and this is my virtual host.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>


        <Directory /var/www/html/domain>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>


        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain
        ServerName domain.com.br
        ServerAlias www.domain.com.br

        ProxyRequests On
        ProxyPreserveHost On

        <Proxy *>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
        </Proxy>

        <Location />
                ProxyPass http://localhost:3010/
                ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:3010
        </Location>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/domain.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/domain.log combined


</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.com.br
    Redirect permanent / http://www.domain.com.br/
</VirtualHost>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Not enough information.  Describe the overall network architecture more, including DNS configuration, where the clients are coming from, what OS they are running, etc...